# UITableView don't scroll when it's only composed of section header

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got an UITableView which contained sections, each with a header view. When you click on a header, the section is expending (so the numbers of rows in the section goes from 0 to X at this moment and rows are inserted with animation)

The problem is that when you don't have any section expended, the TableView won't scroll when you try to go to the bottom for the exemple (when you only have the section headers displayed and 0 row anywhere)

I suspect it's because there is no row at all (because as soon as one section is expended, the TableView is scrolling normally) but I can't find any solutions.

Any idea ?

Comment: according to your question description it looks like you are trying to scroll the table when there are no rows/limited no of rows if you have less rows which is less than view's height,it will not scroll, it will give bounce effect if you keep enabled that ,is there any specific problem occur when you are trying to scroll or can you please tell your expectation and no of rows set in the tableview delegate

Comment: Obviously but that's the things, my number of sections doesn't fit the view's height and I stil canno't scroll. Basically, when no sections are expanded, the number of rows in total in the tableview is 0.

Comment: @ tYp if you have 0 rows in tableview tableview should not show and you will not able to scroll it, though you may enable bounce as mentioned by Palak to get some scroll effect

Answer (score 1):

I would put this in a simple comment but I do not have the reputation to do so. Do the sum of the header views all equate to a height larger than the view that they are in? Additionally, check to make sure you do not have the UITableView does not have the scrolling disabled. If you are unsure, override it with the following code in your `ViewDidLoad()` method in your `UITableView` file:

```
    tableView.scrollEnabled = true
```

Hope this can help, comment if this does not work and I will try to help you fix it.

Comment: If UITableView have section headers only, Scrolling Enabled property needs to be set again to "true", to allow scrolling, even if Scrolling Enabled property is set to in XIB or by code in awakeFromNib or on initWithFrame. Strange! but works...

Comment: Set tableView.scrollingEnabled = true after each [tableView reloadData]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a custom view, an xib file, for your tableView, make sure that the "view" in your xib file is a 'uiview class', not 'uitableviewcell'.

Doesn't matter what custom you use for the view, but the view itself must be a 'uiview'. Delete whatever view you have in your xib, and drag a uiview from object library in xcode and setup from there, your custom class can still be usable by the 'uiview'

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help you

in your viewDidload method

```
 TableView.alwaysBounceVertical =YES; // it is your choice that you want it vertical or horizontal .
 TableView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
```

i used it in my project when my data is smaller for my view but it still my page scrolled.